# ruby on rails NoMethod error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, attributes

```
def owns
  @companies = Company.where(:id => own_clients.id ).paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def own_clients
  @users = User.where(:boss_id => current_user.id)
end
```

This gives me syntax error in own_clients.id part. How can i reach own_cliens 's id?
**EDIT:** Company is a model. Company has_many :users. User is a model. I want to login with userA, then add some other users userB and userC (so userA will be boss of them according to :boss_id), then see which companies userB and userC belongs to. I did add part, just looking for companies see part.

Comment: How do you call owns function?

Comment: '<% provide(:title, 'Own Companies') %>
<h1>Own Companies</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="companies">
 <%= render @companies %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate %>' this is owns.html.erb

Comment: it says undefined id in `@companies = Company.where(:id => own_clients.id ).pa...` part

Comment: Add prints to your own_clients function. And see if it can't call it, or you just get wrong result

Comment: own_clients is working, but i cannot reach their id 's

Comment: what do you get in result to: own_clients. Print it in owns function( not own_clients.id, print just own_clients)

Comment: If you get an array, so try : Company.where(:id => own_clients.map(&:id)), without the brackets you made in the comment below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your method own_clients is returing an array and you an not use ".id" with an array of records.

Solution will be to use 
own_clients.map(&:id) in place of own_clients.id

Answer (score 1):

Assuming own_clients is a model, try this:

```
 own_clients.map &:id
```

Should give you an array of id's within own_clients.

Comment: no no own_clients is just above. its like a variable. i am searching an answer for this
    `def owns
      @companies = Company.where(:id => User.where(:boss_id => current_user.id).id ).paginate(page: params[:page])
    end`

Comment: and this gives me error like this: `syntax error, unexpected tAMPER, expecting tASSOC
...here(:id => { own_clients.map &:id }).paginate(page: params[...` pointing &: